# Applying Filter on dynamic URL's

Tags: java, url, servlets, servlet-filters

I have to filter urls like this :

```
http://www.mysite.com/708e93
```

where `708e93` is a unique id, based on this id i have to create dynamic pages in jsp.

Now the problem is - what do i put in url-pattern under filter-mapping

```
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>foo.bar.MyFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern> ?? </url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

if i put root (/) in url-pattern ..every request to mysite will be filtered ,then in that case how can i get unique id ?

Any solution ?

**EDIT**:

I dont want to add a directory in url like this :`http://www.mysite.com/dynamicpages/708e93`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic url's such as use case you have. you should be have all the dynamic pages inside a directory, lets say `dynamicpages` folder. And you should be mapping a directory url pattern like below :

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>foo.bar.MyFilter</filter-name>  
  <url-pattern>/dynmaicpages/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>foo.bar.MyServlet</servlet-name>  
  <url-pattern>/dynmaicpages/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You can get the Unique id using the following methods:

- `HttpServletRequest.getPathInfo()`  If you have servlet mapping like above, this will give you the unique id value directly.

For ex, if the request uri is `/dynamicpages/708e93`
it will return `708e93`.

- `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURI()` This will give you the entire request url. And you need to parse the unique id properly.

For ex, if the request uri is `/dynamicpages/708e93`
it will return `/dynamicpages/708e93`.

Comment: That is the only neat way. Otherise, you have to keep track of all dynamic pages and filter them in code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ..but i already had this as a solution before posting my question....i just don't want to use a directory....